# Caliburn Micro WindowManager set WindowStyle.None and allow dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm currently very stuck with this, my designer wants to have our app with WindowStyle.None to remove the borders and default ugly controls, he has then add custom controls, usually to allow dragging in the past we have used a rectangle and monitored the mousedown event to allow for dragmove.

However with Caliburn micro we lose control of the window because windowmanager create this for us, I'm aware you can override the create window method, but this still doesn't give access to adding UI elements to the window itself and binding to those events. Or at least i can work out a way to do this.

Basically what we are trying to achieve is the "mainwindow" with a WindowStyle.None and that ability to drag and move the window. My googling has failed to give a solid answer on this, and im hoping someone here has an idea.

Answer (score 4):

Caliburn.Micro doesn't force you to make the all your views UserControls. The main view or the one your showing as the main window **can be** a Window control and you can set properties directly on that Window such as "WindowStyle.None". When Caliburn.Micro sees that the view behind your main view model *(the view model you are using as the root, then one you are creating first)* is actually a Window and not a UserControl then it will honor this and show that window, It **Will Not** create a new Window. So you can set your properties directly on that Window and everything shall work fine.

Comment: I honestly didn't know that, everything i've seen suggests that it always makes the window, this would be perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The Caliburn.Micro `WindowManager` provides overrides to its `Show` methods that allow you to set the settings of the window that is created.

Have a look [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/caliburn-micro-configuring-window-dialog.html) for an example.

Alternatively, you can use a `Window` directly as your view type (in XAML and the generated code behind file), and set the properties declaratively in the XAML.

If you wish to enable all of your dialogs etc to have common UI components, then you could create a derived `WindowManager` type that delegates the call to the CM `WindowManager` but wraps the passed in view model with your common view model. Then register this custom window manager in the bootstrapper rather than the default CM window manager.